# Litecoin-qt getblocktemplate ￼Support for 'segwit' rule requires explicit client support (code -8)

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, litecoin-qt

I have downloaded the Windows version litecoin client from https://litecoin.org/. I am trying to setup CoiniumServ to serve as a LiteCoin Pool.

Most configuration are done.
However, I am facing this issue. When I try to query **getblocktemplate** from the litecoin-cli, I will get this error **Support for 'segwit' rule requires explicit client support (code -8)**.

Can anyone help ? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to explictly declare the segwit rule:

`litecoin-cli getblocktemplate '{"rules":["segwit"]}'`